# Image from content div overlaps sticky footer

Tags: css

I have a pretty annoying issue here. I am using a sticky footer i found on the web, which works perfectly, however I have some big images in the main content area which is overlapping the footer.

Any ideas? [Link to live example - Click on interface to view](http://www.prodigy.org.za/footer_issue/index.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your `#wrapper` you have a negative margin. take that out and it looks just fine

```
#wrapper {
    width: 90%;
    padding: 10px;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto; /** Removed the negative bottom margin **/
    overflow: hidden;
    background: white;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your div `#wrapper` should have a `padding-bottom` equal to the height of the `#footer`, which in your case appears to be 96px. Surely the "sticky footer [you] found on the web" should have mentioned that!